# How can I install Trigram module for Postgresql installed through homebrew?

Tags: postgresql, module, homebrew

So I've installed Postgresql via Homebrew, and it looks like the contrib directory is missing. And all of the tutorials I've read to install Trigram require this.

```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/share/postgresql/contrib
-bash: cd: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/share/postgresql/contrib: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get Trigram installed (pg_trgm.sql)? I'm lost here.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/share/contrib`?

Comment: Yep, doesn't exist...and the only folders in share are doc, man, and postgresql.

Answer (score 5):

Just found out that the correct path is....

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.2/share/postgresql/extension
```

Wanted to share for anyone else running into this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same issue, but found that the correct path is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgis15/1.5.3/share/postgis/
```

Of course check out your PostGIS version number to match your exact path. This folder is where files like postgis.sql or spatial_ref_sys.sql are found... I guess this is what you need?